# Apache wicket validation

Tags: apache, validation, wicket

I have custom validation added to my page, and this validation is called from business logic layer, after I click "Save" button on UI, which is `AjaxSubmitLink`.

On my page I have apache wicket DateTimeField, but it's validation doesn't work correctly: error message doesn't appear in `FeedbackPanel`, which is added on page and my custom validation is shown there correctly.

So for example I fill hours field with "321" and I will have error in console:

> WARN  org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebSession  -
>   Component-targetted feedback message was left unrendered. This could
>   be because you are missing a FeedbackPanel on the page.  Message:
>   [FeedbackMessage message = "Translation for key [hours.RangeValidator]
>   is not found for language [en]!", reporter = hours, level = ERROR]

Maybe someone had similar problems and have solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you have 2 problems. You miss a feedbackpanel and you missing a key in your resource file. Can you show some code?

Answer (score 6):

Because you do an Ajax-Request you have to add the feedback-panel to your `AjaxRequestTarget` (so it will update itself on every request).

You have to override the `onError` method though:

```
add(new AjaxSubmitLink() {
    @Override
        protected void onError(final AjaxRequestTarget target, final Form form) {
        target.addComponent(yourFeedbackPanel);
    }
}
```